# Prevent bash script from exiting with a non zero exit code

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

I have a bash script that I need to keep from exiting if the exit code of the command is greater than 0. The purpose for this is to echo a custom error message. My current code fails as the exit code is > 0 and my echo statement never gets executed. Is there a way to silently ignore the non zero status and print my custom error message?

**Code:**

```
#/bin/bash

# Faulty command
lllll
echo $?
   
if [ "$?" -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Please enter a valid command."
fi
```

**Output:**

```
./test.sh: line 4: lllll: command not found
127
```

Comment: Your test is testing the exit status of the preceding `echo`.

Comment: The reason your second echo isn't getting printed is that $? is getting populated by the return value of your first echo, which is 0. You could immediately store the return value in a different variable after the potentially faulty command and then test it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the problem. Bash will only exit on error if you explicitly tell it to by adding `set -e` to your script. What is happening here is that the variable `$?` holds the exit code of the last command run. In your case, the last command is the `echo $?` so since the `if [ "$?" -gt 0 ]` comes after the `echo $?`, the value of `$?` will be 0 since the `echo` succeeded. Try like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Faulty command
lllll
   
if [ "$?" -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Please enter a valid command."
fi
```

Running the script above produces:

```
$ foo.sh
/home/terdon/scripts/foo.sh: line 4: lllll: command not found
Please enter a valid command.
```

A cleaner way would be to hide the error message:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Faulty command
lllll 2> /dev/null
   
if [ "$?" -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Please enter a valid command."
fi
```

Which produces:

```
$ foo.sh
Please enter a valid command.
```

And, of course, you don't even need the `if` for something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Faulty command
lllll 2> /dev/null || echo "Please enter a valid command."
```

Comment: DUH.. lol Stupid mistake on the `echo $?`. I have been sleep deprived lately. Thank you.